# .htaccess redirecting without port

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect from site.com/foo/bar.php to site.com/foo/bar

I came up with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!clients/).*$ %1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

and to send request to .php file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!clients/).*$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,NC]
```

but above redirects to site.com:8080/foo/bar

The port is getting added, I've tried `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080` and many other things but it didnt work. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!clients/)(.*)\.php$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: it does not redirect it to /file mate :/

Comment: i need it load from /dir/file.php /dir/file....my code does but with the port 8080 also :S

Comment: @user1690718 - Try now (and please remove your above comments)